# A weighted infinite sum of functions attains its maximum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $f_n:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a sequence of continuous functions with $\sum_{n\ge 1}f_n(x)=1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Let $a_n$ be a sequence of numbers in $[0,1]$. Can we show that the function $$S:[0,1]\to [0,1],\quad x\mapsto\sum_{n\ge 1}a_nf_n(x)$$ attains its maximum? (Note that the series defining $S$ is pointwisely convergent.) This is used in a paper that I am reading, but I fail to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ is the limit of an increasing sequence of continuous functions and therefore lower semi-continuous (see, for example, [Properties of semi-continuous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity#Properties)).

By the same argument,
$$
 1 - S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-\alpha_n) f_n(x)
$$
is also lower semi-continuous.

It follows that $S$ is continuous, and therefore attains its maximum on the compact set $[0, 1]$.

*Remark:* The compactness of the domain is not needed to show that $S$ is continuous, only to assert that $S$ has a maximum.

Comment: Dear @Martin R, Many thanks! Your idea is really clever.

Answer (score 3):

By the Dini theorem the series $\sum f_n$ is uniformly convergent. Therefore the series $\sum a_nf_n$ is uniformly convergent as well. Indeed $$0\le \sum_{k=n}^\infty a_kf_k\le \sum_{k=n}^\infty f_k$$Therefore the series $\sum a_nf_n$ represents a continuous function, hence it attains its maximum and minimum.

Comment: @MartinR     The Dini theorem is applied to $\sum f_n$. Then if the series $\sum f_n$ is uniformly convergent so is $\sum a_nf_n$

Comment: You are right, my fault. It's a good argument!

Comment: Dear @Ryszard Szwarc, Your proof is equally nice. Thank you! I accepted the one by Martin R because that is earlier.

Comment: @Doug: Acutally, Ryszard posted their answer 5 minutes before I posted mine. – But that should not play a role, just accept the answer that you find most helpful.